# React js using @react-google-maps/api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

I'm getting some issues, I'm working with react js and I'm adding a google map, using  `@react-google-maps/api` so I just want a map like:

[image]

so I'm using `use-places-autocomplete` and `@reach/combobox` for build elemet input for search places, so, I'm getting some issue that the input elemet "search" is not showing the correct form, I upload the code on codesandbox, you can check it on:

[Mapa on CodesandBox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-booth-l3dv6p?file=/src/mapa.js)

you can tell me what I'm going wrong??? please

Comment: Did you not see "Google Maps JavaScript API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys" in the sandbox console? You haven't been able to load a google map without an API key for almost a decade now, and I remember when they changed they're terms because I had to very quickly port a bunch of apps to open street maps and leaflet.js lol

Comment: on my local I push my Api Key, but on codesandBox I can shared it, so you should understood why....., so, on lmy local when I push my Api Key the map don't show yet.

Comment: I'm not sure what "push my Api Key" means in this context?

Comment: sorry, I mean I used my own api key, and the map was not shown either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in CSS. `<map-container>` has `position: relative;` and `overflow: hidden;` is hiding the fact that the map is loading out of view.

Tinker with the CSS a bit and you'll be set.

Comment: I added    ```position: "absolute"``` and  ```overflow: "none" ``` but the input search don't look correct position https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-booth-l3dv6p?file=/src/mapa.js

Comment: I can't added ```position: "absolute"``` to the input element, right??

Comment: Yeah, the CSS will need to be reconfigured, but the issue is that the map was not displaying. The issue is that the CSS needs to be rewritten to support the configuration you're looking for; but the map itself is fine.